# WCF: Cache SSL data

Tags: c#, wcf, security, ssl, wcf-security

I want to create WCF service and client. I want to add 2 way SSL between these 2 services.

I was wondering, if there is a way that these services will cache the negotiation data of the first connection, and use it in the following connections in order to reduce the latency caused by the SSL handshake.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't avoid handshaking even in case of negotiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL already does session sharing. You don't have to do anything to make it happen.

Comment: Is there a way to get this cache? I mean, as a client, I want to get the data (and to use it as a token).

Comment: @Mattan I don't know the C# API but you can generally get hold of the session ID somehow via whatever API there is. It's just a byte sequence.